# Using $hash for the method setParameter()

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, symfony4

I would like to find out if the user is logged in.

```
public function findByExampleField($data) {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u.email, u.password')
        ->where('u.email = :email')
        ->andWhere('u.password = :password')
        ->setParameter('email', $data['email'])
        ->setParameter('password', $data['password']) // <-- the problem
        ->setMaxResults(10)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

Since the password is hashed, I need to verify it first. In this case I need to use `password_verify($data['password'], $hash)`. My problem is the second parameter. How can I declare the variable `$hash`?

Comment: As mentioned below get rid of `->andWhere('u.password = :password')` and `->setParameter('password', $data['password'])` then run the comparison logic in PHP. Also `->setMaxResults(10)` is an interesting one!

Comment: Just curious, why do you search by password? In your database emails aren't unique? may be easier to search by some other fields, not password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to search by hash.

The hash generated by `password_hash` is unique and includes a random salt each time.

Successive calls to `password_hash` will generate different results. This is very easily verified by doing:

```php
var_dump(password_hash('1', PASSWORD_DEFAULT) == password_hash('1', PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
// bool(false)
```

You can `password_verify` the hash, since it includes all the necessary information (hash+salt+algo), but regenerating the same hash to look it up on the DB it's not possible.

Basically what you are attempting to do is not only a bad idea, it is not possible.

What you do is get the user by it's username or email (whatever unique identifier you have for the user), and then you verify the password:

```
$user = $userRepository->findUserByEmail($email);

$loggedIn = password_verify($inputPassword, $user->getPassword());
```

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the user and ditch the WHERE clause for the password. Then you can get the hashed password and check it in PHP.

And I'm guessing you wouldn't have more than one row per email address so you can ditch MaxRecords too.